# Is there any algorithm to validate Australian TFN number?

Tags: javascript, c#, vb.net, algorithm, validation

We are looking to validate Australian TFN numbers entered by our clients.
Is there any official algorithm mentioned somewhere?

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_file_number) mentions about a simple modulo-11 algorithm but it seems it is just an example.

Comment: The example on that page does give the weightings for each digit. The same algorithm is provided [here](http://www.mathgen.ch/codes/tfn.html) (and other places). But as both pages say, officially the ATO doesn't provide details of the algorithm even though it's well known what it is.

Comment: Yes, but that's what. Until there is something official we can't rely on those weighting factors otherwise we may end up throwing errors for valid numbers as well. :)

Comment: There is an ABN validation algorithm here but nothing for the TFN -
https://abr.business.gov.au/HelpAbnFormat.aspx

Comment: The ABN code is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14174738/regex-to-match-australian-business-number-abn/42661127#42661127

Answer (score 5):

**In Javascript 9 Digit:**

```
var tfn = $('#tfn').val();

//remove spaces and update
tfn = tfn.replace(/\s+/g, '');
$('#tfn').val(tfn);

//remove hyphens and update
tfn = tfn.replace(/[-]/g, '');
$('#tfn').val(tfn);

//validate only digits
var isNumber = /^[0-9]+$/.test(tfn);
if(!isNumber) {
    return doError('Invalid TFN, only numbers are allowed.');
}

//validate length
var length = tfn.length;
if(length != 9) {
    return doError('Invalid TFN, must have 9 digits.');
}

var digits = tfn.split('');

//do the calcs
var sum = (digits[0]*1)
        + (digits[1]*4)
        + (digits[2]*3)
        + (digits[3]*7)
        + (digits[4]*5)
        + (digits[5]*8)
        + (digits[6]*6)
        + (digits[7]*9)
        + (digits[8]*10);

var remainder = sum % 11;

if(remainder == 0) {
    doSuccess('Valid TFN, hooray!');
} else {
    return doError('Invalid TFN, check the digits.');
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/steveswinsburg/tfn-validator/blob/master/tfn-validator.html

**In C# 9 Digit:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int count = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();
    while (count < 500000) {                
        int randomNumber = random.Next(100000000, 999999999);
        if (ValidateTFN(randomNumber.ToString()))
        {
            sb.AppendLine(randomNumber.ToString());
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("TFNs.txt", sb.ToString());
}


public static bool ValidateTFN(string tfn)
{
    //validate only digits
    if (!IsNumeric(tfn)) return false;

    //validate length
    if (tfn.Length != 9) return false;

    int[] digits = Array.ConvertAll(tfn.ToArray(), c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));

    //do the calcs
    var sum = (digits[0] * 1)
            + (digits[1] * 4)
            + (digits[2] * 3)
            + (digits[3] * 7)
            + (digits[4] * 5)
            + (digits[5] * 8)
            + (digits[6] * 6)
            + (digits[7] * 9)
            + (digits[8] * 10);

    var remainder = sum % 11;
    return (remainder == 0);
}

public static bool IsNumeric(string s)
{
    float output;
    return float.TryParse(s, out output);
}
```

Ref: https://softwaredevelopers.ato.gov.au/obtainTFNalgorithm

**In C# 8 Digit:**

```
public static bool ValidateTFN(string tfn)
{
    //validate only digits
    if (!IsNumeric(tfn)) return false;

    //validate length
    if (tfn.Length != 8) return false;

    int[] digits = Array.ConvertAll(tfn.ToArray(), c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));

    //do the calcs
    var sum = (digits[0] * 10) 
            + (digits[1] * 7)
            + (digits[2] * 8)
            + (digits[3] * 4)
            + (digits[4] * 6)
            + (digits[5] * 3)
            + (digits[6] * 5)
            + (digits[7] * 1);

    var remainder = sum % 11;
    return (remainder == 0);
}
```

Ref: https://jeremythompson.net/Rocks/TFN_algorithm_8_digit.pdf

**In VB.Net 9 Digit:**

```
Public Shared Function ValidateTFN(ByVal tfn As String) As Boolean
        If Not IsNumeric(tfn) Then Return False
        If tfn.Length <> 9 Then Return False
        Dim digits As Integer() = Array.ConvertAll(tfn.ToArray(), Function(c) CInt(Char.GetNumericValue(c)))
        Dim sum = (digits(0) * 1) + (digits(1) * 4) + (digits(2) * 3) + (digits(3) * 7) + (digits(4) * 5) + (digits(5) * 8) + (digits(6) * 6) + (digits(7) * 9) + (digits(8) * 10)
        Dim remainder = sum Mod 11
        Return (remainder = 0)
    End Function
```

**In PHP 9 Digit:**

```
function ValidateTFN($tfn)
{
    $weights = array(1, 4, 3, 7, 5, 8, 6, 9, 10);
 
    // strip anything other than digits
    $tfn = preg_replace("/[^\d]/","",$tfn);
 
    // check length is 9 digits
    if (strlen($tfn)==9) {
        $sum = 0;
        foreach ($weights as $position=>$weight) {
            $digit = $tfn[$position];
            $sum += $weight * $digit;
        }
        return ($sum % 11)==0;
    } 
    return false;
}
```

Ref: https://clearwater.com.au/code/tfn

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.. the weighing digits in your solution are same on the Wikipedia page but are they the official ones from the tax department, any clue?

Comment: Yes they are. You can contact the Australian Tax Office directly @nnnnnn: http://softwaredevelopers.ato.gov.au/obtainTFNalgorithm. I work in finance and have this code in production. Its correct.

Comment: It is important to note that TFNs nowadays are 9-digit, but in the past some were 8-digit. The weightings for the 8-digit TFNs were (10, 7, 8, 4, 6, 3, 5, 1). In future the ATO expects there will be 10-digit TFNs which will again have different weightings

Comment: @e_i_pi very interesting, is there an official source available for these 8-digit TFN weights? Edit: I found this https://github.com/sidorares/tfn/files/290459/Tax_file_number_.TFN._algorithm_8_digit.pdf for anyone interested

Comment: Added the 8 digit formula.

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 5:**

Make sure you use keyboard type Number Pad to prevent users from adding non-numeric characters.

```
func isTFNValid (tfn: String) -> Bool{
    if (tfn.count != 9) {
        return false
    } else {
        let characters = Array(tfn)
        let digits = characters.map { Int(String($0))!}
        //do the calcs
        var sum = (digits[0]*1)
                + (digits[1]*4)
                + (digits[2]*3)
                + (digits[3]*7)
                + (digits[4]*5)
                + (digits[5]*8)
                + (digits[6]*6)
                + (digits[7]*9)
                + (digits[8]*10)

        var remainder = sum % 11;

        if(remainder == 0) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you [Jeremy Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson) for the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

An implementation that supports **Java 8** and possibly higher

```
public class TFNUtils {
    public static String format(String tfn) {
        if (tfn == null) {
            return null;
        }
        tfn = tfn.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        tfn = tfn.replaceAll("\\-", "");
        if (tfn.length() != 9) {
            return null;
        }
        int sum = (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(0))))
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(1)))*4)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(2)))*3)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(3)))*7)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(4)))*5)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(5)))*8)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(6)))*6)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(7)))*9)
                + (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(tfn.charAt(8)))*10);
        if ((sum % 11) != 0){
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder tfnCompute = new StringBuilder(11);
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(0));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(1));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(2));
        tfnCompute.append('-');
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(3));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(4));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(5));
        tfnCompute.append('-');
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(6));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(7));
        tfnCompute.append(tfn.charAt(8));
        return tfnCompute.toString();
    }

    public static boolean isValid(String tfn) {
        return format(tfn) != null;
    }
}

public class TFNUtilsTest {
    @Test
    public void testFormat() throws Exception {
        assertEquals("123-456-782", TFNUtilsTest.format("123-456-782"));
        assertEquals("123-456-782", TFNUtilsTest.format("123456782"));
        assertEquals("123-456-782", TFNUtilsTest.format("123 456 782"));

        // invaild returns null
        assertNull(TFNUtilsTest.format("123 456 7829"));
        assertNull(TFNUtilsTest.format("123 456 78"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsValid() throws Exception {
        assertTrue(TFNUtilsTest.isValid("123-456-782"));
        assertTrue(TFNUtilsTest.isValid("123 456 782"));

        assertFalse(TFNUtilsTest.isValid(null));
        assertFalse(TFNUtilsTest.isValid(""));
        assertFalse(TFNUtilsTest.isValid("123-456-780"));    // invalid check-digit
        assertFalse(TFNUtilsTest.isValid("123-456.782"));    // invalid seperator
        assertFalse(TFNUtilsTest.isValid("123-456-7820"));   //  > 9 digits
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have checked the c# code shared in this post, Actually the generated TFN number using that code has failed with the TFN validation in the mentioned WebSite. So I came with an alternate solution with the help of this website https://clearwater.com.au/code/tfn to generate valid TFN.

Try this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            Random random = new Random();
            while (count < 50)
            {
                int randomNumber = random.Next(100000000, 999999999);
                // - Validate TFN - [START]
                float output;
                //validate only digits
                string strRandomNumber = randomNumber.ToString();
                if (!float.TryParse(strRandomNumber, out output))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Input");
                }
                else
                {
                    //validate length
                    if (strRandomNumber.Length != 9)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Length");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        int[] digits = Array.ConvertAll(strRandomNumber.ToArray(), c => (int)Char.GetNumericValue(c));

                        //do the calcs                   
                        var sum = (digits[0] * 10)
                                + (digits[1] * 7)
                                + (digits[2] * 8)
                                + (digits[3] * 4)
                                + (digits[4] * 6)
                                + (digits[5] * 3)
                                + (digits[6] * 5)
                                + (digits[7] * 2)
                                + (digits[8] * 1);
                        var remainder = sum % 11;
                        // - Validate TFN - [END]
                        if ((remainder == 0))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(randomNumber.ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the same as my code, except its more verbose, procedural and you mix the business logic code with the Console GUI code. Apart from those mistakes its a direct copy of my answer and the link you provided is for PHP.